# Cannot set div's display style to block in an event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve behaviour where my overlay div gets visible over the whole page after a button click. I was trying to use both jquery syntax with `.show()`/`.hide()` and `getElementById` functions but couldn't get it done. The code below outputs with "1st state: block" and "2nd state: none", although it should be "2nd state: block" and the div doesn't get visible at all. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("save-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
        // $("#overlay").show();
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';
        var state = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display;
        console.log("1st state: " + state);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/myUrl?arg1=$(arg1)&arg2=$(arg2)",
            data: {arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2},
            success: function (response) {
                var state = document.getElementById("overlay").style.display;
                console.log("2nd state: " + state);
                // $("#overlay").hide();
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
            },
            error: (resp) => {
                // $("#overlay").hide();
                document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        // $("#overlay").hide();
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
})
```

html:

```
  <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
  <button id="save-button">Save</button>
```

css:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Why the weird mix of jQuery and DOM? Classic JS and ES6? Your code should be `$(function() {
  $("#save-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/myUrl",
      data: {
        arg1: arg1,
        arg2: arg2
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("#overlay").hide();
      },
      error: function(response) {
        $("#overlay").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});` and make the button a type="button"  just in case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of your `document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';` call just after the `$.ajax` call (line 22~23). The [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method is asynchronous and will return immediately, causing the overlay to be directly hidden.

You should only hide your overlay in your `$.ajax` callbacks.

Remove that line and you should be ok:

```js
$(function() {
  var overlay = $("#overlay");
  $("#save-button").on("click", function() {
    overlay.show();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/myUrl",
      data: {
        arg1: arg1,
        arg2: arg2
      },
      success: function(response) {
        overlay.hide();
      },
      error: function(response) {
        overlay.hide();
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Also, if you're using POST requests, why also pass the data as GET parameters? Plus, your code style is strange (sometimes `function`, sometimes arrow, etc), I suggest you use a linter to be consistent.

Comment: And get rid of DOM calls now he has jQUery

Comment: Indeed, I just updated the code to use jQuery more properly.